# Can I run a new process from a medium-trust ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, hosting, medium-trust

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC site where I want to use [OpenSTV](http://www.openstv.org/) to conduct polls. To run results through OpenSTV, I'd have to run the executable. **Is that allowed from a medium-trust** ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't instantiate a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object unless you're running at `FullTrust`.

If you examine the attributes decorating the class you'll see the demand for `FullTrust`:

> [Process Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

```
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, 
        SharedState = true, Synchronization = true, 
    ExternalProcessMgmt = true, SelfAffectingProcessMgmt = true)]
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public class Process : Component
```